# The type '' cannot be used as type parameter '' in the generic type or method ''. There is no implicit reference conversion from '' to ''

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am trying to implement some generic in View - Controller classes. My "framework" looks like that:

*Controllers:*

```
public interface IController<TView> where TView : IView
{
    // some generic fields / methods definitions
}

public abstract class BaseController<TView> : IController<TView> where TView : IView
{
    // some generic fields / methods implementation
}

public interface IConcreteController
{
    // some specific fields / methods definition
}

public class ConcreteController<TView> : BaseController<TView>, IConcreteController where TView : IView
{
    // specific implementation
}
```

*Views:*

```
public abstract class IView : UserControl // MARKER
{
}

public class BaseView<TController> : IView where TController : IController<IView>
{
    // some generic fields / methods implementation
}

public abstract class IConcreteView : BaseView<IConcreteController>
{
    // some specyfic fields methods definition
}

public class ConcreteView : IConcreteView
{
    // some specific fields methods implementation
}
```

But I get an error in *IConcreteView* file:

> The type 'IConcreteController' cannot be used as type parameter
>   'TController' in the generic type or method 'BaseView'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from 'IConcreteController'
>   to 'IController'.

What should I fix to get this "template" to work?

**Update:**

As **Ned Stoyanov** suggest:

I chenged *ConcreteView* to:

```
public class ConcreteView<TController> : BaseView<TController>, IConcreteView where TController : IController<IView>
```

and *IConcreteView* to:

```
public interface IConcreteView
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your definition of `IConcreteView`

```
public abstract class IConcreteView : BaseView<IConcreteController>
```

It iherits from `BaseView<IConcreteController>` and the class `BaseView<TController>` has a constraint that `TController` must be an `IController<IView>`

```
BaseView<TController> : IView where TController : IController<IView>
```

But `IConcreteController` is not an `IController<IView>`, it's just a stand alone interface, hence the error message.

I am not sure that the interfaces `IConcreteController` and `IConcreteView` are achieving much, I'd just get rid of them altogether.